# NSDateFormatter dateFromString give wrong result

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/d/YYYY"];
NSDate *addedDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:weightDTO.dateAdded];
[dateFormat release];
NSLog(@"dateAdded %@", weightDTO.dateAdded);
NSLog(@"addedDate %@", addedDate);
```

This print the following in a loop with 2 entries.

```
dateAdded 06/2/2012
addedDate 2011-12-18 18:30:00 +0000

dateAdded 06/8/2012
addedDate 2011-12-18 18:30:00 +0000
```

So it is supposed to get a 2012 date for addedDate object. However the result is different. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: there should be : [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/d/yyyy"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `dateFormat` to this -

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```